# Как программно сделать строку в Xcode UITableview текущей?

Tags: uitableview

Как программно сделать строку в `UITableview` текущей и перейти на нее?
Не могу найти в инете, как программно сделать текущей строку в `UITableview`. 
Например, как переместиться в конец списка после выхода из subview?

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так `[firstTable selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];`